# Custom space after continuous section break

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document with a few short sections (say two or three on each document page).
Each section has 1 or + paragraphs and is separated from the others by a continuous section break.

I want to edit the space after the section break. How can I do that?
I've googled "custom space after continuous section break" and, surprisingly, I couldn't find much.

A standard section break adds too much white space, a continuous section break does the job but I'd like to to add more breathing space between each section.

Comment: You need to adjust the formatting of the item **following** the continuous section break. For example, if it is a paragraph then increase the space before.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks David. The problem with this solution is that sections 2 and 3 are ok but I have a weird gap at the beginning of the doc before section 1 and every time the previous section ends at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You need to adjust the formatting of the item before the first continuous section break. For example, if it is a paragraph then decrease the space after.

Answer (score 2):

`View` tab -- select `Draft` mode

This lets you see the section breaks. You can now select it and format as you would text or anything else. Modify the `Paragraph` settings to add additional space after should do what you are wanting.

Set up a new style for section breaks if you need this in a number of different places.